# Fourier transform to determine stability of fixpoint of equation with temporal convolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, convolution

Given the differential equation

\begin{align} 
\frac{d v}{d t} = - v(t) +  \kappa * v 
\end{align}

where $\kappa$ is some linear temporal filter (like a sum of two exponentials, for instance) and $*$ denotes temporal convolution. Moreover,  given we know the fixpoint,  can we check its stability simply by taking the Fourier transformation and looking at the real part of the derivative with respect to $\hat v$ at every Fourier frequency?

I.e. can I do the following?

\begin{align}
F[\frac{d v}{d t}] = F[- v +  \kappa * v] 
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\leftrightarrow \frac{d \hat v}{d t} = - \hat v(n) +  \hat \kappa(n) \hat v(n) 
\end{align}

And then simply look at the real part of $d \hat f/d \hat v$ with $\hat f = - \hat v + \hat \kappa \hat v$? Thus, the fixpoint is stable if $- 1 + Re (\hat \kappa (n)) < 0$ for every Fourier frequency $n$?

Thanks, and sorry for any inconvenience regarding the layout of my question. I only have access to my phone right now, which makes typing formulas difficult. Any refactoring appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean with the Fourier transform. Is it wrt. to $t$? But then I would not expect $dv(hat)/dt$ but $in$ times $v(hat)$.

Comment: Yes, with respect to time. I know that $F[dx/dt] = 2 \pi i n \hat x$. So my question boils down to if I can happily ignore this relation and do the following $F[dx/dt] = d F[x] / dt$ $ since both - Fourier transform  as well as the derivative - are linear operations?

Comment: But $F[x]$ does not depend on $t$. It is integrated over.

Comment: Hmm, but could we interpret this in such a way, that the frequency does depend on time? Ie $\hat v$ gives as the frequency spectrum at one particular point in time, which may actually change in case the frequency fix point has not been reached yet, thus the time series $v(t) $ won't show the frequency spectrum. However, in case $\hat v$ has reached the fixpoint, the in time series we observe $v(t) $ manifests this spectrum and we'll see the oscillations as given by $\hat v$.

Comment: Similar thought: what about taking the Fourier transform from $-\infty $ to $t$, ie now the result does depend on $t$. That makes sense since usually temporal filters only take into account events that happened in the past.

Comment: Since you are interested in both time and frequency aspects you could have a look at wavelet transforms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet